# Are the orders of $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ all distinct, as $n$ varies?

Tags: group-theory

I came up with a following question. Say $n$ and $m$ are distinct square-free positive integers.

Can we have the case that
$$|\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})| = |\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})|?$$

Since $n$ is square-free, the order must be equal to
$$n^3 \prod_{p \mid n} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p^2}\right).$$

And my question is whether these values, as $n$ varies, are all distinct.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hints*. Note $|\mathrm{SL}_n\mathbb{Z}|$ is multiplicative as a function of $n$, and has the same largest prime factor as $n$.

Comment: Of course! Thanks, that just solved the question instantly!

Comment: This is not exactly true. $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb Z/2)$ has size $6$, with largest prime factor $3$, not $2$.

Comment: @KentaS Ah true, $p+1$ is not even and indeed is itself prime when $p=2$. Since $p\ge2+1$ for $p>2$ this should be the only counterexample.